# How to form deformed slats of horizontal aluminum blinds back into shape?

Tags: blinds, aluminum

Is there a way to return 100%-functional aluminum slats closer to original optically uniform shape? When looking at their profile, it is slightly bent shape like `⌢`, 0.15 mm thick. Ideally in-place, without disassembling the blind.

See the third and fourth slat from the top, which are deformed:

[image]

The same photo with highlights to ease finding them on the above photo:

[image]

Comment: Some things cannot be fixed.  The blinds fit that description, unless you have the same tools that originally stamped them.  Or you can import a metal worker with decades of experience in hand forming metal.  Or just buy a new blind.

Comment: You can want all sorts of things you aren't going to get - this would be one of them.

Comment: The wording wasn't the problem. The way you make perfect slats is with new aluminum stock that isn't deformed and suitable tooling. Once they've been bent there's no getting back to the original shape.

Comment: @Ecnerwal – you started the comment directly referring to the wording I used... but OK, let it be. I improved the question by asking for way to get let's say at least 80% result.

Comment: @RMDman – yes I know such a men who can more-less fix it, but I thought this thing is such a common knowledge, that I can easily get similar answers here before I consult possibilities with them.

Comment: Fixing bent aluminium blinds is far from common. What is common is they are replaced.

Comment: Fixing them as part of the blind is hard.  Taking them apart can probably make two wood/metal forms and press a single blind piece at a time back in shape.  If not needing to be perfect, might be able to de-bend a bit with your hands in place.

Comment: Or use a pipe as a curved  anvil and hammer them back into shape...?

Comment: @keshlam – idea like this is what I expect so I wondered why experienced users write that there is simply no way. I will try this.

Comment: Because it's a pain in the arse, it's likely to leave you needing to then repaint, simply unstringing and restringing venetian blinds is a pain in the posterior, and replacements aren't _that_ expensive. Now go out and prove 'em wrong. (Caveat: I can't promise success; haven't tried it myself.)

Comment: @keshlam – thank you. FYI, where I live, all venetian blinds are custom-made, i. e. length of each exactly corresponds to window width (with 1 mm tolerance) and color is picked from palette of about 40 options, and each shop has its own palette which also changes over the time. Therefore I cannot simply buy a spare ones (I can do it short time after getting originals and then cut them into proper length, with round corners, and pierce all holes in correct distances) and this is why it is beneficial for me to learn how they are fixed.

Comment: Ah. Good luck, then.